# Internal F# error with F# 3.0 in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012, f#-3.0

I have installed the Developer Preview of the Visual Studio 11 along with F# 3.0. If I open a F# project it is opened with no warnings or errors and FSI starts normally, but as long as I start testing it by sending my code to FSI (via contextmenu -> "Send To Interactive") I immediately see the following error message:

```
Error FS0193: internal error: Value cannot be null
```

If I fall back to VS2010 and F# 2.0 (I installed VS11 in parallel on the same machine) it works without any problem. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** It is difficult to derive a minimal example for this error, but I found that a similar problem was reported on FPish [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59792). Especially the cryptic message `Parameter name: con`.

I spent several hours trying to simplify my programm but I failed to identify the line where the code would fail. It looks as if there were some problems with type inferred from usage: it either complains that the type is too generic and not constrained or fails with the internal error if I add some usages to help F# determine the type. It happens only in a really complex context, simple type infererring cases work fine...

Comment: I have VS11 and VS2010 in the same machine, but have no problem with F#. Does the code work if you type directly in F# Interactive? Does the problem occur with a specific code fragment?

Comment: Since this may be something about the actual F# code in question, probably you want to post a sample of the code that throws this error.  I mean I think you're assuming this would happen with any F# code but that's not necessarily a safe assumption.

Comment: @pad : I tried to add some relevant information, but couldn't get any reproducible code. See the corrected post.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci : I editted my post above.

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: I'm aware of the above problem, but they observed it with F# 2.0 compiler. If you don't provide more context, it's impossible to tell what's going on here.

Comment: @pad I would love to provide more context, but I can reduce it only on module level and it is about 10 Kb code in two modules that lead to this behaviour. Should I just add them to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try sending this as a bug report to fsbugs at microsoft dot com.  (Thanks to Tomas Petricek for posting that e-mail address in a different answer.) I think that would be your best approach at this point.

Comment: Yes, I know this email too, but I am not sure if there is a clear bug and, the most problematic, I can't derive any minimal example: my code is interdependent and I see this error only after I have fed in the complete module.